# How do I export a Community Template from the Lightning Community Builder?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, community-builder, developer-edition, template

In the Salesforce Winter '17 "Using Templates to Build Communities" Docs  (http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/11/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf) the steps for exporting a Community Template begin with:

`Go to Settings > Developer.`

[image]

However, I can't find this **Developer** menu in my Developer sandbox (see below).

[image]

Is there another setting that I need to set in order to make this menu visible?  I'd really like to export a template to explore how Community Templates are structured.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you update the template to the latest in your builder .Can you screenshot what you see currently ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I've added a screenshot so you can see what I see. And the the Napili theme from Winter '17.

Comment: Thats weird because in my dev org i see it .Let me check couple things

Comment: @MohithShrivastava thanks, I'm new to the Community Builder, so it's possible I've got a certain permission wrong.

Comment: Can you click on the updates tab to see which version you are in ? Also try in other developer orgs .Spin a new community in other orgs and see if you still running into the issue

Comment: @MohithShrivastava here's my [version](http://imgur.com/a/N38Ka).

Comment: @MohithShrivastava also, just made a new community in the same org and still don't see any **Developer** menu.